How to Convert Mac Outlook .olm file to PST
I am using outlook on mac and trying to export .OLM file and convert it to PST file(windows) for analysis purpose. Any idea how to transform outlook .OLM file into PST?

MS states it can be done through a Microsoft Exchange Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/import-and-export/cannot-import-olm-file-into-outlook-for-windows Have you tried that?

Agree with DrMoishe Pippik, we cannot convert Mac Outlook .olm file to PST directly in Outlook for Mac.

Is there any updates?

I'm half convinced this is a spam seed. Kinda waiting for the other shoe to drop.
